# diff 2 files with an output that does not include extra lines

Tags: linux, bash, unix, diff

I have 2 files test and test1 and I would like to do a diff between them without the output having extra characters 2a3, 4a6, 6a9 as shown below.

```
mangoes
apples
banana
peach
mango
strawberry
```

test1:

```
mangoes
apples
blueberries
banana
peach
blackberries
mango
strawberry
star fruit
```

when I diff both the files

```
$ diff test test1
2a3
> blueberries
4a6
> blackberries
6a9
> star fruit
```

How do I get the output as

```
$ diff test test1
blueberries
blackberries
star fruit
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to strip the leading `<`'s and `>`'s? that's going to get confusing unless you have a very simplistic case....

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep` to filter out lines that are not different text:

```
$ diff file1 file2 | grep '^[<>]'
> blueberries
> blackberries
> star fruit
```

If you want to remove the direction indicators that indicate which file differs, use `sed`:

```
$ diff file1 file2 | sed -n 's/^[<>] //p'
blueberries
blackberries
star fruit
```

(But it may be confusing to not see which file differs...)

Comment: Eliminate the superfluous grep. `diff file1 file2 |  sed -n '/^[<>] / { s/^[<>] //; p; }'`

Comment: Eliminate the superfluous match. `diff file1 file2 | sed -n 's/^[<>] //p'`

Comment: Thank you ! :) I was trying to do it with sed but failed. Much appreciated :)

Comment: @user1234sdfg : Next time show your failed try with `sed` (we like to see people trying) and now you can accept this answer (showing thanks to @dawg and showing others you do not need more help for this question).

Answer (score 2):

A solution using `comm`:

```
comm -13 <(sort test) <(sort test1)
```

**Explanation**

> comm - compare two **sorted** files line by line
>
> With no options, produce three-column output.  Column one contains
>          lines unique to FILE1, column two contains lines unique to FILE2, and column three contains lines common to both files.
>
> -1     suppress column 1 (lines unique to FILE1)
>
> -2     suppress column 2 (lines unique to FILE2)
>
> -3     suppress column 3 (lines that appear in both files

As we only need the lines unique to the second file `test1`, `-13` is used to suppress the unwanted columns.

[Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) is used to get the **sorted files**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} !($0 in a)' test test1
```

- `NR==FNR` means currently first file on the command line (i.e. test) is being processed,
- `a[$0]` keeps each record in array named `a`,
- `next` means read next line without doing anything else,
- `!($0 in a)` means if current line does not exist in `a`, print it.